# Получаю пустые поля при запросах из БД

Tags: linux, база-данных, golang, sqlite3

Практикую язык GO, решил для саморазвития написать простой стилер паролей из хрома,скопировал Login Data, подключение и запрос из базы проходят, но возвращаются пустые поля при открытие sqlite3 browser также нет данных, возникает следственно вопрос БД как-то защищена? либо данные хранятся в другом месте? ОС Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: Если база пустая, то и возвращать она должна пустые значения или как-то так.

Comment: Но у меня же в браузере сохранены логины и пароли, как она может быть пустая? Следственно данные пишутся в другое место ?

Comment: Откройте её в консоли `sqlite3 Login\ Data` и наберите `.output chrome_passwords.txt`, а потом `.quit`. А потом `less chrome_passwords.txt` и если файл пустой, то значит и база пустая. Хотя, судя по всему, если SQLite3 Browser показывает её пустой - значит она пустая.

Comment: Я так уже делал, результатов не было, ну тогда возникает вопрос, откуда браузер подтягивает пароли?

Comment: Если Вы с открытым Хромом этот файл копировали, то полагаю, всё из-за этого. Т.к. если есть сохранённые пароли, то в базе они должны быть. Но Хром открывает базу эксклюзивно, что запрещает доступ файлу. А там, уже в зависимости от того, чем и как копировали. Хром, даже закрытый может иметь фоновые процессы, которые будут использовать этот файл (т.е. блокировать его). И ещё, может быть разработчики Хром временно перестали использовать SQLite3 из-за уязвимости Mаgelann. Но это маловероятно.

Comment: Попробовал всяко разно, даже с другого компьютера его взять, как удивительно, что размеры файла совпадают, но стандартная функция в хроме по выгрузки в csv работает нормально, видимо хитро там все.

Comment: Ну вот, в 2011 всё работало под Windows: https://habr.com/post/134982/

Comment: Вот, [тут](https://askubuntu.com/a/525062/233299) говориться, что Chrome и Chromium выбирают либо Gnome Keyring либо KWallet в зависимости от среды рабочего стола. Т.е. файл Login Data используется только в очень старых версиях под Linux. Я проверил у себя KWallet, действительно пароли там.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть три способа хранения паролей в Chromium и Chrome:

- GNOME Keyring
- KWallet 4
- Просто текст

Способ определяется автоматически на основе среды рабочего стола. Для GNOME это GNOME Keyring, для KDE - KWallet. При использовании GNOME Keyring или KWallet, если были какие-то пароли, сохранённые как текст, то они перемещаются в зашифрованное хранилище.

В `man google-chrome` описана следующая опция

```
--password-store=<basic|gnome|kwallet>
      Set the password store to use.  The default is to  automatically
      detect  based  on  the  desktop  environment.  basic selects the
      built in,  unencrypted  password  store.   gnome  selects  Gnome
      keyring.  kwallet selects (KDE) KWallet.  (Note that KWallet may
      not work reliably outside KDE.)
```

Используя флаг `--password-store=basic`, можно сохранять пароли как простой текст (разумеется не рекомендуется).

Таким образом, файл `Login Data` используется только в очень старых версиях Chrome и всегда пустой. Нет возможности использовать его для хранения паролей.

---

[Источник](https://askubuntu.com/a/525062/233299)